# js `this` context in a callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, this

Given class functions

```
game.PlayScreen = me.ScreenObject.extend({  

    onResetEvent: function() {
        this.setAll(); //calls setAll(), which calls setGlobals()
        this.saveNextLevelData(this.setAll);
    },

    saveNextLevelData : function (callback) {
        $.get("./php/CRUD.php", {},
            function (returned_data) {
                callback(); //however, the callback of setAll throws 
                           `undefined is not a function` error
            }
    },

    setAll : function () {
         log("setAll called");
         this.setGlobals();
    },

    setGlobals : function () {
         log("setGlobals called");
    }
});
```

Basically, I'm confused on how `this` context is lost when you call a callback function.

In the above code,

- **Works**: `this.setAll()` called directly from `onResetEvent` outputs `"setAll called"` and `"setGlobals called"`
- **Breaks**: `callback()` calling `this.setAll()` from `$.get` outputs `"setAll called"` but `this.setGlobals();` breaks... I think due to lost `this` context... It outputs `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

I'm trying to follow the context of `this` when you call a callback function which contains a function belonging to the parent object (`this`, in this case). If I want to call `this.setGlobals()` from a callback of `this.setAll()`, where exactly do I need to do the bind?

Thanks

Comment: You asked [nearly the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22364352/confused-on-prototype-bindings-this-statement) two months ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is best to pass the context from the caller part, it can be done using [$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)/[Function.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) so

```
this.saveNextLevelData($.proxy(this.setAll, this));
```

Another solution will be is to pass the current object as the context to the callback from the ajax callback, the problem is by default `this` in the callback will refer to the ajax settings object. so

```
saveNextLevelData : function (callback) {
    var self = this;
    $.get("./php/CRUD.php", {},
        function (returned_data) {
            callback.call(self);
        }
},
```

Comment: `$.proxy()` returns a function reference which will call the function passed as first param with the context as the object passed as the second param

Comment: @Growler: Maybe you should read the docs he provided for you.